# Specific split of string

Tags: python, string, split

I have this string:

```
youtube.com.    3599    IN  TXT "google-site-verification=OQz60vR-YapmaVrafWCALpPyA8eKJKssRhfIrzM-DJI"
youtube.com.    3599    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:google.com mx -all"
youtube.com.    3599    IN  TXT "facebook-domain-verification=64jdes7le4h7e7lfpi22rijygx58j1"
```

And want this splitted version as a list out of it:

```
[youtube.com.,3599,IN,TXT,"google-site-verification=OQz60vR-YapmaVrafWCALpPyA8eKJKssRhfIrzM-DJI",youtube.com.,3599,IN,TXT,"v=spf1 include:google.com mx -all",youtube.com.,3599,IN,TXT,"facebook-domain-verification=64jdes7le4h7e7lfpi22rijygx58j1"]
```

With split() function for string its splitting every string seperated by a blank space, but i want split every line into 5 strings seperated by the first 4 blanks in a line.
How is that possible? (Preferable with not much code)

Thank you in advance,
Greetings

Comment: Can you show what you expected results would be?

Comment: You might try using regex for this [Regex How To Is Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split a string and keep spaces inside quotes, you can use [`shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
import shlex
import itertools

s = '''youtube.com.    3599    IN  TXT "google-site-verification=OQz60vR-YapmaVrafWCALpPyA8eKJKssRhfIrzM-DJI"
youtube.com.    3599    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:google.com mx -all"
youtube.com.    3599    IN  TXT "facebook-domain-verification=64jdes7le4h7e7lfpi22rijygx58j1"'''

out = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(shlex.split(line, posix=False) for line in s.splitlines()))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['youtube.com.', '3599', 'IN', 'TXT', '"google-site-verification=OQz60vR-YapmaVrafWCALpPyA8eKJKssRhfIrzM-DJI"', 'youtube.com.', '3599', 'IN', 'TXT', '"v=spf1 include:google.com mx -all"', 'youtube.com.', '3599', 'IN', 'TXT', '"facebook-domain-verification=64jdes7le4h7e7lfpi22rijygx58j1"']
```

Comment: Thanks, thats working.
But when i write the output `'"google-site-verification=OQz60vR-YapmaVrafWCALpPyA8eKJKssRhfIrzM-DJI"'` to a file using csv.writer it is written as  `"""google-site-verification=OQz60vR-YapmaVrafWCALpPyA8eKJKssRhfIrzM-DJI"""`
Do you know why it uses two `"` extra?

Comment: @asdfyxcvqwer you can try to set `posix=True` in `shlex.split` and it will remove extra `"`

Comment: thank you that works.
I have another problem though, sometimes the last string in " has " in it too, (example: `"v=spf1 include:google.com "mx" -all"`. I want to take it as one string still. How can i fix that? Is their a maxsplit parameter in shlex.split maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a maximum number of splits with [`maxsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
my_string.split(maxsplit=4)
```

> If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit number of splits occur, and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element of the list (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements)